# How can I get MAME to show sensible scan line effects for the Fairchild Channel F?

Tags: emulation, mame

I've just started using HLSL in MAME to get that classic scan line look, and it works a treat — most of the time.

However, I'm trying to get my `channelf` games to quadruple their scan lines (like the original console did). By that I mean:  each row of pixels occupies *four* scan lines on the CRT, as you can observe by fullscreening [this video.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wBeokwN_5jg&t=5m9s)

I'm not having any luck, though. Mine comes out looking like this instead.  (The snapshot mechanism screwed up the aspect ratio here, but you can see what I mean.)

[image]

The effect clearly thinks: "one row of pixels = one scan line, what's the problem?". Ha. At 58 pixels vertical, that's not gonna cut it.

Anwyay, the `prescale` option doesn't do anything to help, even though it seems like it should be exactly what I want.

Any clues?

(I'd also be interested to know where to put any config file(s) that applies *only* to `channelf`.  Obviously I don't want what I'm asking for here done elsewhere.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently the functionality I was looking for here is not intended; the fix is to alter the emulation code to output the pixels as seen by the CRT, which is actually 2× horizontally and 4× vertically (5× on PAL).

https://mametesters.org/view.php?id=8012

So, please wait warmly…